# html link visible in email received twig

Tags: html, twig

Any idea why the `<a>` link is still visible when I see it in an email? 
For example, I have this code in twig:

```
Please click 
<a href="{{ base_url }}{{ path('send.email.user', {'token': token }) }}">here</a> 
to confirm the email. <br/>
```

And when I receive the email it looks like this:

```
Please click <a href="http://local.app.com/confirmation/rir3Y0v3Pqw">here</a> 
to confirm the email. <br/>
```

Also the `<br />` tag is visible so I guess the html is not seen. But why? Any suggestions?

EDIT:

```
$message = $this->emailService->getMessage(
    'user@yahoo.com',
    'User confirm',
    'ApplicationBundle:UserEmail:email.html.twig',
    array(
        'token' => $this->emailService->getEmailTokenService()->createToken()
    )
);

$this->emailService->send($message);
```

Comment: How are you sending the email? Please show us your code.

Comment: I'm sending using the SwiftMailer.

Comment: @JorgeValle I edited.

Comment: Also make sure you do not have an escape somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the body to be sent in `text/html` or else it will be sent in `text/plain`. I don't have your complete code, but here is something I used, adapted to your code. `$this->tmpl` is my template object which is used to render the view.

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('User confirm')
    ->setFrom('user.from@yahoo.com')
    ->setTo('user.to@yahoo.com')
    ->setBody(
        $this->tmpl->render(
            'ApplicationBundle:UserEmail:email.html.twig',
            array(
                'token' => $this->emailService->getEmailTokenService()->createToken()
            )
        ),
        'text/html'
    );

$this->emailService->send($message);
```